# Accessing a property that has an object as it's value

Tags: reactjs, api, react-props

I'm working with an API that retrieves data from a request from a user. The data returned looks something like

```
{
name: "mewtwo"
id: 150
types: Array(1)
     0:
     slot: 1
     type: {
          name: "psychic", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/14"
      }
}
```

I want to access the "psychic" value in type but I receive an undefined for "type". I'm able to display the name property and id just fine I just can't get the "psychic" value.

```
const Display = (props) => {
    console.log(props.data.types);
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="pokemon-name">{props.data.name}</h1>
            <p>{props.data.id}</p>
            <p>{props.data.types.type.name}</p>//Will throw an error here
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: `types` is an array, so it's `types[0].type.name`

Comment: well that makes sense - it's an array? you will either need to access it via index or map over it...

Comment: I still get an error 'Cannot read property of '0' undefined'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an array element. Change it to the following

```
props.data.types[0].type.name
```

```
const Display = (props) => {
    let { data } = props;
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="pokemon-name">{data.name}</h1>
            <p>{data.id}</p>
            <p>{data.types[0].type.name}</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data.types` is an **Array** of **Objects**, I think you want to access the first entry in the data.types array. 
So I'd replace `{props.data.types.type.name}` with `{props.data.types[0].type.name}`.

For safety reasons I'd check for the existence of that array and extract the data out of it before using it like so:

```
const Display = ({data}) => {
    // destructure properties out of data prop
    const { name, id, types } = data;
    // extract type name
    const typeName = types[0].name;
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="pokemon-name">{name}</h1>
            <p>{id}</p>
            <p>{typeName}</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

Taking in account that your data is coming from an API, the `types` prop may not be populated when you're trying to access it. We can account for that scenario like so:

Here's a wrapper component example. this component gets the async data and renders the `Display` component.

```
// import as you would to make React work.    
class Wrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataFromApi: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // async function to get data from api (ex: fetch)
        fetchDataFromAPI().then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            this.setState({ dataFromApi: data })
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { dataFromApi } = this.state;

        return dataFromApi ? 
            (<Display data={dataFromApi}>) : 
            (<span>loading</span>);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense .

Cheers!